# Send DNS queries in Java without using InetAddress

Tags: java, dns, udp

I am trying to send DNS queries to a DNS root server(eg. 192.58.128.30) using JAVA. But the thing is, I am not allowed to use library functions like InetAddress.getByName(), how to proceed?

I have tried this so far:

```
    public class Main{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            DatagramSocket client = new DatagramSocket();

            String rawMessage = "example message";
            byte[] message = rawMessage.getBytes(); //converting the message into a byte array

            //creating datagram packet
            DatagramPacket packet =
            new DatagramPacket(rawMessage,rawMessage.length,InetAddress.getByName("192.58.128.30"),53);

            //sending packet using datagramSocket
            client.send(packet);

        }
    }
```

EDIT: The issue was solved.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us some code.

Comment: @amedina I have edited my post. The main issue is that, I am not allowed to use the InetAddress library in this code. How to send the DatagramPacket without using InetAddress?

Comment: Why can't you use the library?

Comment: @Ctorres, to be honest, I am doing an academic project and the manual said, using InetAddress library is forbidden.

Comment: That explain a lot! Haha. Sorry, I can't help you, I though it was just a missing dependency problem. Goodluck!

Comment: Oh. No problem. Thanks anyways :D @Ctorres

Comment: If I was you, I would probably check what this function does exactly and tried to do something similar with my own function.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :D @Ctorres

Comment: Answer your own question if you finally do it, this could help someone! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to figure out what the function really does and implement the method manually for learning purposes.

Comment: Reimplementing what was done in a library and probably debugged and optimised is not necessarily the best solution, except if the purpose is to learn things.

Comment: Yes. It is solely for learning purpose @Patrick Mevzek I have edited my answer. Thanks :D